# SqlConnection.ClearAllPools issue

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, ado.net, connection-pooling

I am using VSTS 2008 + .Net 3.5 + C# + ADO.Net + SQL Server 2008 Enterprise. I am learning http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearallpools.aspx about SqlConnection.ClearAllPools method. I want to know the behavior of this method is, if any connections from connection pool is idle when method ClearAllPools is called, such idle connections will be disconnected from SQL Server? Is that correct understanding?

I did not find related comments from the MSDN link.

Comment: why do you want to clear the connection pools? Are you sure you don't have some other problem?

Comment: I am learning some other people's code. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is Yes.
But the situations in which this is useful are rare.